# What is the correct parameter type for the zeroes function?

Tags: matlab

> num = input('Enter the size')

I want to create a 2 dimensional matrix matrix of dimensions numx2 using num. So I use zeroes(num, 2);

However I get this error

```
Undefined function or method 'zeroes' for input
arguments of type 'double'.
```

I tried casting to a uint8 and an int8 and it didnt work so I looked up the matlab documentation but it doesnt give the parameter types for functions. So anybody know how to create this 2d matrix using the value of num that I get from the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function you want to use is [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/zeros.html) not `zeroes`

Comment: Thank you Prætorian for adding the link.